# Geofencing in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, geofencing, flutter-web3

I tried Geofence in Flutter web and Easy Geofencing, but both automatically trigger an exit event. I don't know why. If anyone knows, please tell me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to give mor details like the exact stack trace and your code. In this state, the questions don't have enough details to be anwsered

Comment: i m not able to give full code here but i tried https://pub.dev/packages/easy_geofencing/example,this example in my code with lat and long ,radius but it is going exit state in flutter web,and i tried geofence_flutter package ,but not working i dont why,is there any way to do geofence in fluter web